# WCF / WCF Ria Service returns relational data in "IncludedResults"

Tags: c#, json, wcf, silverlight, ria

WCF/ WCF ria services return proper data when we call it in a silverlight application using invoke an operation, 
but when we use this service in angular or call it from postman returns relational data outside the RootResults with separate "IncludedResults".

Service/API method -

```
public IQueryable<viewauthor> getauthors(int author_id)
        {
            IQueryable<viewauthor> lstAuthor = null;
            lstAuthor = this.ObjectContext.books.Include("books").Where(p => p.author_id == author_id).AsQueryable();
            IEnumerable<viewauthor> lstResult = lstAuthor.ToList().Trim();
            return lstResult.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Entity framework metadata "author.metada.cs" -

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ViewAuthor.ViewAuthorMetadata))]
    public partial class ViewAuthor
    {
    public string AUTOR_ID { get; set; }
    ....
    ....

    [Include]
    public EntityCollection<books> Books { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    }
```

Actual JSON Response from "getauthors" API -

```
{
  "SelectDocDetailsByMattterIDResult": {
    "TotalCount": 1,
    "IncludedResults": [
      {
        "__type": "books:#library.Web.Data",
        "book_id": 1,
        "title": "Test book 1"
      },
      {
        "__type": "books:#library.Web.Data",
        "book_id": 2,
        "title": "Test book 2"
      },

    ],
    "RootResults": [
      {
        "author_id": 1,
        "ADD_TIME": "\/Date(1559300437353+0530)\/",
        "name": "test author"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected JSON -

```
{
  "SelectDocDetailsByMattterIDResult": {
    "TotalCount": 1,
    "RootResults": [
      {
        "author_id": 1,
        "ADD_TIME": "\/Date(1559300437353+0530)\/",
        "name": "test author",
        "books": [
          {
            "__type": "books:#library.Web.Data",
            "book_id": 1,
            "title": "Test book 1"
          },
          {
            "__type": "books:#library.Web.Data",
            "book_id": 2,
            "title": "Test book 2"
          },

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need the same JSON response as SilverLight application, What I did wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you define the service interface, and which binding the server uses? Please refer to my definition.

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Product> SayHello();

    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }


    }
    public class Animal
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Result.
[image]
Besides, the default serializer is XMLSerializer, we could use DataContractSeriailizer to simplify the serialization, please refer to below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @abraham Qian. 
I am using existing WCF ria service API's with direct use of entity framework with navigation property and "include" method of EF.

In WCF ria services there is not written any operation contract and data contract, entity object used directly. These API's responses working correctly with the SilverLight app.

And I am developing Electron App with angular by using those existing API's. 
So, I have to implement DTO(data transfer object) or DataContract to get correct JSON response for this?

Comment: In my opinion, the format of the data response does not satisfy the specification you want because there is a problem with the serialization and deserialization of the entity class. 
In addition, creating a Restful-style API may convenient for the call of your project, so I use webhttpbinding.

Comment: Okay, Extremely thankful for your reply and for giving me your precious time.Thank you.

Comment: What do you think of this issue? Which aspect do you think we should undertake to solve this issue? Sorry for my poor English. I could not understand the issue clearly, I would like to know how do you design the service contract and how to call the service and get the JSON data on the client-side.

Comment: Actually, I reached the conclusion that there is a problem with the serialization of entity framework entities. So, I will create a separate Data Transfer Object (DTO) class that has similar properties as an entity. Use these DTO to hold the data and return in response of API instead of actual entity return. May be it will work.